# Error on build and run flutter project after reinstall windows

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

when i install new windows on my computer and install and configure android studio unfortunately my project that i have build on previous windows got error on below and i don't know what is about?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signingConfigWriterDebug'.
> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: 
 E:\Project\Mobile_App\store\build\app\intermediates\signing_config\debug\out\signing-config.json

 * Try:
 Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more 
 log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

 BUILD FAILED in 6s
 Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Does the user logged into that computer have full admin access to all folders?

Comment: Thank you , it's worked

Comment: My pleasure! Glad I could help.

Comment: To fix just remove 'build' folder from the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

From the build error, it looks like that it has issues accessing the signing-config.json from the `build` folder. Try deleting the build folder then run `flutter clean` and `flutter run` to rebuild the project.